# <h1></h1> tag only partly responsive

Tags: html, css

The first `h1` tag I use in my code works for me with the styling I'm going for but the second and third ones don't. The second one does not become a heading at all (just plain small text) and the third is too big.

```css
h1 {
    color: #2B2B2B;
    white-space: normal;
    word-break: break-all;
    font-family: Georgia;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <img src="Logo.png" alt:"">
    <div class="container">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>About Us</li>
                <li>Services</li>
                <li>Continuing Education Courses</li>
                <li>Support Groups & Workshops</li>
                <li>First Appointment & Fees Insurance</li>
                <li>Blog</li>
                <li>Contact</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <hr>
        <div class="profile-box">
            <img src="Group 1.png" alt="" align="center" width="300px" height="100px">
            <main>
                <section>
                    <h1>Grounding and Resourcing Technique Giveaway</h1>
                    <h2>
                        Being a mental health clinician can be such an empowering and rewarding role. You can change,
                        help, and nourish so many of those struggling with everyday life. Through the responsibilities
                        you take on while helping others, it’s so important to practice grounding and resourcing
                        techniques with your clients.
                    </h2>
                </section>

                <div class="child-one child" <h1>Bill Maceus, Co-Founder of XYZ is giving away a FREE handout for
                    grounding and resourcing methods.</h1>
                    <img src="Rectangle 817.png" alt="" align="left">
                    <h2>
                        Learn ways to keep your client grounded by establishing comfortability, learning breathing and
                        body awareness techniques, object-based resourcing, and so much more. This handout will help you
                        overcome some of those challenges you face daily as a mental health clinician while working with
                        clients.
                    </h2>
                    <hr>
                    <h1>Simply fill out the form below to download.</h1>
                    <h2>You will be sent a copy to your email.</h2>
                </div>
            </main>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a syntax error in your HTML. The following line is incomplete:

`<div class="child-one child"`

Anything that comes after that line may produce unexpected results. You need to complete the opening div tag (and also close it somewhere, if that is your complete code).

`<div class="child-one child">`

Comment: Also, which I don't think was your actual problem here, h1 tags inside of a section element may be styled differently in your browser. An h1 inside of a section is treated like a subheading and usually styled like an h2. You can see this happening if you move your first h1 out of the section element. It will be the same size as the other h1 elements on the page. Inside the section, however, it's nested deeper into the structure of the page and therefore displayed differently. This only affects h1s, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<style>` tag to enclose the css.

```
<style>
h1 {
    color: #999999;
    white-space:normal;
    word-break: break-all;
    font-family: Georgia;
    text-align:center;
}
</style>
```

You also forgot the closing tag for div, though not entirely sure where you want the placement for closing tag would be.

```
<div class="child-one child"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VS Code editor, install Auto Close Tag extension if you haven't yet to avoid this kind of problem and Prettier extension as well is a big help for you to looks your code organize and easy to see what is wrong.

Links:

Auto Close Tag extension - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.auto-close-tag

Prettier extension - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <img src="Logo.png" alt:"">
    <div class= "container">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>About Us</li>
       <li>Services</li>
        <li>Continuing Education Courses</li>
        <li>Support Groups & Workshops</li>
        <li>First Appointment & Fees Insurance</li>
          <li>Blog</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <hr>
    <div class="profile-box">
    <img src="Group 1.png" alt="" align="center" width="300px" height="100px">
    <main>
    <h1>Grounding and Resourcing Technique Giveaway</h1>
    <section>
      <h2>
        Being a mental health clinician can be such an empowering and rewarding role. You can change,
 help, and nourish so many of those struggling with everyday life. Through the responsibilities you take on while helping others, it’s so important to practice grounding and resourcing techniques with your clients.
      </h2>
    </section>
    
    <div class="child-one child">
      <h1>Bill Maceus, Co-Founder of XYZ is giving away a FREE handout for grounding and resourcing methods.</h1>
      <img src="Rectangle 817.png" alt="" align="left">
      <h2>
        Learn ways to keep your client grounded by establishing comfortability, learning breathing and body awareness techniques, object-based resourcing, and so much more. This handout will help you overcome some of those challenges you face daily as a mental health clinician while working with clients.
      </h2>
       <hr>
       <h1>Simply fill out the form below to download.</h1>
       <h2>You will be sent a copy to your email.</h2>
    </div>
    <style>
      h1 {
        color: #2B2B2B;
        white-space:normal;
        word-break: break-all;
        font-family: Georgia;
        text-align:center;
      }
    </style>
</body>
```

You had a lot of errors such as no closing body or div tags, and now all of them are the same size.

Answer (score 0):

You leave a closing tag on div class

```
<div class="child-one child"
  <h1>Bill Maceus, Co-Founder of XYZ is giving away a FREE handout for grounding and resourcing methods.</h1>
```

Please complete the code to be:

```
<div class="child-one child">
```